# Using Jquery load to fill div but block specific script?

Tags: html, jquery

As part of a Chrome extension I provide for free to players of a browser game I’d like to load the contents of one of the game’s pages in a side panel I’ve added and then style it to fit the panel. This all works great except the page in loading has a script that changes the game menu bar to that pages selection. Now unfortunately every time my panel loads it changes the menu button selected. Is there any way to use load() and block a specific script or function? I can’t just load the body because they head contains other functions that I need.

Any help or advice is appreciated!

Here is the code block I'm currently using to load the side panel:

```
//**************************load the events panel**************************
if (document.URL.indexOf("combat_events.game") < 1 )
{
$('#hzevents').load('https://www.heroesrisinggame.com/game/combat_events.game', {}, function(){
$( "#hzevents" ).contents().find( "#happeningNow" ).css( "display", "none" );
$( "#hzevents" ).contents().find( ".event_title" ).css( "font-size", "14px" );
$( "#hzevents" ).contents().find( ".event_title" ).css( "background", "none" );
$( "#hzevents" ).contents().find( ".event_content" ).css( "margin-left", "10px" );
$( "#hzevents" ).contents().find( "h2" ).css( "font-size", "14px" );
$( "#hzevents" ).contents().find( "h3" ).css( "font-size", "12px" );
$( "#hzevents" ).contents().find( ".btn" ).css( "padding", "4px" );
$( "#hzevents" ).contents().find( ".framed" ).css( "width", "200px" );
$( "#hzevents" ).contents().find( ".row" ).css( "display", "grid" );
$( "#hzevents" ).contents().find( ".row ~ div" ).css( "display", "none" );
$( "#hzevents" ).contents().find( ".row ~ div" ).css( "padding-bottom", "60px" );
$( "#hzevents" ).css( "height", "auto" );
$( "#hzevents" ).css( "min-height", "270px" );  
});
}
```

Comment: Hi, try to post some specific code please, other devs will not be able to help you, see this page for details > https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and specifically how to build minimal reproducable example of your issues > https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example I think that you will have even more trouble because extensions are limited more AFAIK

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out I didn't need the entire remote page because many of the scripts required for the page to work are on all of the pages. I was able to change the load function to only bring over an element with an ID of events and that did the trick.

```
$('#hzevents').load('https://www.heroesrisinggame.com/game/combat_events.game #events', {}, function(){
```